# How to use cookies to track session count?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I want to display ann offer pop up depending on what session (first time vs 2nd time opening website) a user is on.

To be clear, this should be depending on if a user has closed out of my website and re enters. Session 2, does not happen simply because he opened another tab on my website.

How do I do this?

React cookies. My thought was to add a cookie count whenever the component is unmounted? But is there a better option or place for this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.